# finite-state machine excessive state

Tags: regex, state-machine

I have i finite-state machine.
My regular expression is: `\+[0-9]+\+%\+[0-9]+`
The problem is that q3 is is in excessive state (the same as q1) I am wondering how to bypass that.
Should I simply rename q3 to q1 or what?
Thanks.
[image]

EOS - end of string.
If you don't remember RegX.
It is basically means that accepted string will be: "`+[0-9]`([0-9] any amount of times, but at least one.)`+%+[0-9]`"([0-9] any amount of times, but at least one)

UPD1 new FSM, question the same: q4 is the same as q2 how to overcome that?

Comment: I really don't understand your question, but I thought I'd point out that your FSM actually only matches `\+[0-9]*\+%\+[0-9]+` rather than `\+[0-9]+\+%\+[0-9]+`; that is, it allows the first set of digits to be empty. You need to split your q₁ into two states. Also, I think that properly speaking, your q₂ should be three separate states, one for each of the characters `+` and `%` and `+`, though I suppose the current notation is clear enough as it is.

Comment: Yep, I've made mistake, but it hasn't influenced the question.

Comment: What tools are you using here? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Microsoft Visio, but if you are confused about FSM it's not for some real purpose, just university project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't a problem here. You write that q₄ "is the same as" q₂, but that's not true: only one of them leads to q₃ if you give it `+%+`, and only one of them leads to q₅ if you give it end-of-string. Therefore, they have to be represented by separate internal states.

Comment: You a probably right, I just had a little argument with my friend about it, so thanks for answer, it helped, also thanks for finding that error.